# Android NFC Mifare Classic authentication issue

Tags: android, encryption, nfc, mifare

I wrote some code for authenticating to and reading from Mifare Classic cards on Android. It works perfectly on the first generation of Nexus 7 (2012) as well as on Samsung Galaxy Nexus I9250. However, it fails on a Samsung S3 Mini. The devices detects the card correctly as MifareClassic and I can use the `connect()` method of the `MifareClassic` object to connect to the tag, but it can't authenticate using either of the two available methods `authenticateSectorWithKeyA` or `authenticateSectorWithKeyB`. However, with the same code, authenticating and reading the data works correctly if using any of the other devices mentioned above!

My questions are:

1. Is the authentication/encryption of the communication a hardware operation? Or is that done in software?
2. Why can the device connect to the tag but not authenticate to it?

Comment: Can other tag reader apps read the contents of your MF Classic card? What code did you actually use to access the tag?

Answer (score 0):

The NFC chips of certain Android devices do not support (the-nonstandard) Mifare Classic tags. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775832/exclude-non-nxp-android-phones-with-nfc-like-the-nexus-4-10) question.

Comment: In my case, Samusung S3 Mini reads the Mifare Classic cards perfectly. It's the decryption method which fails! Thx