# How to detect if device can read and write Mifare classic NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

Is there any way I can check whether the device can read and write Mifare classic NFC tags? I am writing an app which main use case is to read and write Mifare classic tags, so if it can not, the app should show a message and close.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775832/exclude-non-nxp-android-phones-with-nfc-like-the-nexus-4-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public boolean deviceSupportsMifareClassic() {
    FeatureInfo[] info = mContext. getPackageManager().getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    for (FeatureInfo i : info) {
        String name = i.name;
        if (name != null && name.equals("com.nxp.mifare")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the classes in android.nfc.tech you can enumerate a list of TagTechnologies from a scanned tag.

From the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/TagTechnology.html:

> It is mandatory for all Android NFC devices to provide the following
>   TagTechnology implementations.
>
> - NfcA (also known as ISO 14443-3A) NfcB (also known as ISO 14443-3B)
> - NfcF (also known as JIS 6319-4) NfcV (also known as ISO 15693) IsoDep
> - Ndef on NFC Forum Type 1, Type 2, Type 3 or Type 4 compliant tags
>
> It
>   is optional for Android NFC devices to provide the following
>   TagTechnology implementations. **If it is not provided, the Android
>   device will never enumerate that class via getTechList().**
>
> - MifareClassic
> - ...

(emphasis mine)

I am not sure if this is enough for you or if you need to distinguish between a tag simply not offering Mifare Classic and the *device* not implementing support for it? Or even, if you need to determine device support before even scanning a tag?

Comment: I want to determine the device support when opening the app, without having to scan a tag.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any published API for that I'm afraid. I couldn't find any obvious hidden API's either, if that would have helped you. This is likely up to the specific NFC implementation of the device.

Comment: You can detect whether NXP chip is available on the device, however this is not rock solid.

Comment: Yes but would this give a conclusive answer to the OPs question? Nxp likely would support classic, but what's to say others won't too?